# Using join throws exception that cannot be debugged

Tags: c#, linq, join, select

I've got a very simple code snippet to test how to use "join" to connect 2 data parts together, as below:

```
class Employee
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
}
class Department
{
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
class UseJoin
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = new[]
        {
            new Employee{ EmpName="John", DeptId=1 },
            new Employee{ EmpName="Kate", DeptId=2 },
            new Employee{ EmpName="Dave", DeptId=1 },
            new Employee{ EmpName="Dane", DeptId=3 },
            new Employee{ EmpName="Greg", DeptId=4 },
            new Employee{ EmpName="Tony", DeptId=4 },
        };

        IEnumerable<Department> departments = new[]
        {
            new Department{ DeptId = 1, DeptName = "math" },
            new Department{ DeptId = 3, DeptName = "physics" },
            new Department{ DeptId = 4, DeptName = "history" },
            new Department{ DeptId = 5, DeptName = "mandarine" },
        };

        var result = from e in employees
                     join d in departments
                     on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
                     select new { e.EmpName, d.DeptName };
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Upon running this program, console window prints exception/error as below:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<JoinIterator>d__38`4[UseNullable.Employee,UseNullable.Department,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]]
```

I tried to debug, but seems this declarative linq cannot be debugged directly, visual studio keeps prompting error messagebox.

Where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It isn't an error, it's just a type of your link expression with anonymous type. You can iterate it and see the content

Comment: If you want to see the result try `var myList = result.ToList()`. Put a breakpoint after that line and look at the contents of `myList`. Does that give out any exception?

Comment: There is no department for Id 2 which is null.  The fix is as follows : (d.DeptName == null)? string.Empty : d.DeptName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, you're not getting any errors. When creating queries the way that you just did you end up with an `Enumerable` which is not evaluated until you actually want to retrieve the data inside it.

To force it to get the data you could do something like this:

```
var myList = result.ToList();
```

This will force the `Enumerable` to be evaluated and then using a breakpoint after this line you can inspect the `myList` variable and see what values you have in it.

About your `Console.WriteLine(result);` line - this is not working because what actually happens is that `WriteLine` will actually call `.ToString()` on your `result` parameter. The output of `ToString` is not the content of your query or list but the fully qualified name of the object's type. More on `ToString` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8).

In order to print out the content of your query you will need to iterate through it like so:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.EmpName + " - " + item.DeptName);
}
```

This will force the evaluation of your `Enumerable` and print your employees and departments one by one each on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

This code will iterate and display you a result of `Linq` expression.

```
var result = from e in employees
                join d in departments
                    on e.DeptId equals d.DeptId
                select new { e.EmpName, d.DeptName };

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.EmpName);
    Console.WriteLine(item.DeptName);
}
```

You can also expand the Results View in debugger and check the values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your result type IEnumerable. You cant directly print the IEnumerable directly. You have to loop the result and print the object explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

just use a foreach to output your result.

```
foreach(var item in result) {
     Console.WriteLine($"Employee name: {item.EmpName}, Department name: {item.DeptName}");
}
```